# How to implement a working day from 4AM - 3:59AM?

Tags: angular, fullcalendar

I am having trouble finding the correct way to implement a working day from 4AM to 3:59AM.

For example our working day starts at 17-10-2020 4AM and ends at 18-10-2020 3:59AM. We want to show events on the month view that have a start date of 18-10-2020 2AM as if it were on the 17th.

We have implemented slotmaxtime and nextDayThreshold but that only works for events that have a startdate on the 17th and enddate on the 18th. Is there any configuration we are missing that supports this situation?

Comment: I would suggest to substract 4 hours from the registered time values. (but i am new to angular)

Comment: @Luuk it's nothing to do with Angular, it's all about how fullCalendar works. fullCalendar isn't an Angular-specific thing. Your actual suggestion is ok as a workaround though

Comment: Niels, unfortunately I what you want isn't possible with fullCalendar, I'm sorry. All you can really do is the workaround that Luuk suggests, which would do a job but it is far from ideal obviously

Comment: I've already tried that workaround but since we are showing the times in the monthview as well, the times don't represent the correct time anymore. I've opened up a bug because it works in weekview so in my opinion it should work in monthview as well... Let's see what that response will be. (https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/5897)